# data never retrieved from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to retrieve an object from the database by its id

```
public List<User> getCreatorOfCandidature(String userId)
{
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.child("users");
    final List<User> users= new ArrayList<User>();
    Query query = ref.equalTo(userId);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            try{
                for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    User user = data.getValue(User.class);
                    setCreateurDeLaDemande(user);
                    users.add(user);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            }
        }
        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { }
    });
    return users;
}
```

this is a screenshot of my DB
[image]

i'm not sure if the problem is the query or the variable setting inside the onDataChange.

Please note that in the User Object, all getters and setters and the default constructor are defined.

*************************** EDIT******************************************
Here i call my function to retrieve the user.

```
public void setCandidatureFinale(Candidature candidatureFinale)
{
    Demande demande = ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).demandeActuelle;
    demande.setCandidatureFinale(candidatureFinale);

    //recuperer le createur de la candidature pour la MAJ
    List<User> users=getCreatorOfCandidature(candidatureFinale.getUserId());
    User user=users.get(0);
    user.setNbIntervention(user.getNbIntervention()+1);
    user.setGainTotal(user.getGainTotal()+candidatureFinale.getPrixPropose());
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.child("users").child(candidatureFinale.getUserId());
    ref.setValue(user);

    Toast.makeText((Activity) context, "La candidature a été acceptée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Post your db structure

Comment: @HristoStoyanov done

Comment: replace equalTo with child,  ref.child(userId);

Comment: so many people are having trouble retrieving from Firebase

Answer (score 0):

```
equalTo
```

Does not work that way, it must be chained with orderBy*()

Check the docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

If you are looking for a user with a particular UID, try this

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild("yourUserIdField").equalTo(UID);
query.addChildEventListener(new ...)
```

Comment: Still not getting the user. i pass the right key and all but always getting an empty list when i call the function **getCreatorOfCandidature**. please look above, I added the call to the function